# Firebase Crashlytics fails to report crashes

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm switching from Firebase CrashReport to Firebase Crashlytics. I followed the Firebase document ([1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)) and created force crash ([2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash)). And the result is bellow.

```
[Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'ccfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for submission
 ...
[Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=e4bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}
```

It looks like a crash report was packed but failed to send it. I searched the error message on the web, however, I couldn't find any hints.

How can I send crash report to the dashboard?

Additional information:

- I used firebase in multiple schemes and multiple firebase apps in one target.
- I used only named GoogleService-Info.plist for each firebase app before. But now, for the Crashlytics I create add the copy script before `Fabric/run`

  ```
  if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then
    echo "Debug"
    cp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleServices/GoogleService-Info.aaaa.plist" 
       "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
  elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    ...
  fi
  "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
  ```

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. The most likely issue is that a build and run of your app wasn't detected. I'd try doing a build and run of the app without causing a crash and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, I finally solved the problem...
The way is that I removed the app in fabric console and re-link from firebase with app build according to the Firebase doc...

I guess that the link between firebase and fabric was wrong because of the Fabric app in my local environment.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing your solution. I'll chat with the team on this further.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. Crashes would freeze installed of actually crashing, and nothing was reported. My problem was that I was linking against both Firebase Crash and Firebase Crashalytics. Once I removed the old Firebase Crash from my build it started working.